# page.evaluate() is not printing console message

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm a beginner in Javascript as well in `phantomjs`. I'm trying to run this simple console program. But it's not printing `This is page evaluating!`. As well i can see this message on console `Page is opened successfully`.

Here is my program:

```
var page=require('webpage').create();

page.open("https://www.google.com/", function(){
    console.log("Page is opened successfully");

    page.evaluate(function(){
        console.log('This is page evaluating!');
    });

    phantom.exit();
});
```

Complete output:

```
Page is opened successfully
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register to the [`page.onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html) event to see the `console.log()` from the page context printed to the console, because the page context (inside `page.evaluate()`) is sandboxed and those events are not automatically shown.

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
    console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
};
```

Register to the event before the call to `page.evaluate()` which contains the `console.log()` that you're interested in. Most of the time this should be done after initializing the global variables:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log('remote> ' + msg);
};

page.open("https://www.example.com/", function(){
    console.log("Page is opened successfully");

    page.evaluate(function(){
        console.log('This is page evaluating!');
    });

    phantom.exit();
});
```

Other helpful events are: [onResourceError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [onError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html) and [onResourceError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html).

Comment: But my question, Why `page.evaluate` ***NOT*** prints anything? Suppose i want to capture a form where i want to see my email for check. So how would i achieve it?

Comment: That's what I answered. You need to register to the console message event before you `console.log()` something in the page context.

Comment: Then please explain what you are looking for. You're asking why the `console.log` inside `page.evaluate` isn't printed and I answered that the page context (`page.evaluate`) is sandboxed and needs the console handler to passthrough the message from the page context.

Comment: So, do i need to copy your program inside `page.evaluate` function? Are you sure, it will print.? At this time, I'm on phone.. That's why i'm asking!

Comment: No, the event has to be registered before `page.evaluate()` is called. There is no reference to `page` inside the page context.

Comment: StackOverflow (SO) is not a discussion forum. If you have a specific follow-up question, you should ask a new question. But note that the question you just asked in the comments is will be closed on SO, because it is a recommendation request. Now to your question... It's not clear what you mean. PhantomJS is a headless browser. Why are you asking for an alternative? Did you run into a problem with PhantomJS?

Comment: Use `setInterval`. Contrary to popular belief, no one is getting paid to sit 24 hours on SO and answer questions. I have a live and a job.